# How to remove external dependencies from class

Tags: c++

I have used many times some external dependency functions in my main cpp, I try to prepare my code for unit testing, so I would like to replace external dependencies with mock implementations, how will I convert those to mock implementations in my main cpp file?

```
//ExternalDependencies.hpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>

namespace lab04{
namespace task_common{
namespace project{

uint32_t lab04::task_common::project::CalculateID(const uint32_t id)
{
    constexpr uint32_t temp= 0xFFF0;
    return id& temp;
}

inline StreamType lab04::task_common::project::GetType(const uint32_t width) 
{
    switch (width)
    {
        case 1:
            Type = Type::Short;
            break;
        case 0:
            Type = Type::Long;
            break;
        default:
            THROW(ConfigErr, "Eror!");
    }
    return Type;
}

uint32_t lab04::task_common::project::CalculateBS(const uint32_t Count, const uint32_t Size)
{
    return ((Count + 146) *(Size * 1676));
}

} 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem description, I can really only guess what you exactly want to achieve. But as a general statement: Unit testing almost always stands and falls with robust clean interface usage of the classes (and/or their parametrization) you want to test, at least if mocking/stubbing is the way to go. So if your classes to test use a lot of data types from the standard library you want to mock, apply a fitting abstraction for this input for your classes. For sure, this is always a question of proportionality at least if the classes are actually not meant to exist in a polymorphic context. If that's the case, mocking might not the way to go then.